# Identify if possible one or more vectors that can be removed from the span without changing the spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra

u = (2,0,1) ; v = (1,2,1); w = (4,4,3)
Identify if possible one or more vectors that can be removed from the span without changing the spanning set.
please help me with this question, how do I identify it?
thank you in advance! XD

Comment: Write as rows of a matrix. Do row reduction. If you get a row of zeros then a vector can be removed as it must be a linear combination of the others. Any vector will do.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Paul Not true in general, though it works for these vectors. If some row vanishes in row reduction you know there is _some_ nontrivial relation between the original rows, but without having done additional book keeping you won't know which relation. And you can only remove a vector if it has a nonzero coefficient in the relation. (In the example the only relation has no zero coefficients.) It is in fact better to use the vectors as _columns_ before starting row reduction; then any relation you find ultimately will also be a relation between the original columns.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen OK, you can't take out any vector. Never really thought that one through!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \\ 3\end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 - 1 \\ 2 - 0 \\ 3/2 - 1/2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$